# FreeBSD's vi does not do control-D unindent properly?

Tags: freebsd, vi

I'm on a minimalist FreeBSD system and need to use the [*built-in* vi](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vi&sektion=1) editor to edit files. To be specific, this is not vim, or vim-tiny or other replacement. It's the "4BSD bug-for-bug compatible" nvi editor.

It works almost as expected. The [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vi&sektion=1#VI_TEXT%09INPUT_COMMANDS) says that control-T and control-D will indent/unindent according to `shiftwidth`. Control-T does work, but control-D does not. It actually enters the ^D character into the file.

If I do get vim onto the system, control-T and control-D work as expected, so it's not an issue of the terminal mis-interpreting the key. Vi itself is not interpreting control-D.

Anyone run into this? An solutions? Using vim is not an option.

Comment: FWIW, same on OpenBSD.

Comment: @Kusalananda Not encouraging ... a bug in that bug-for-bug claim?

Comment: I'm guessing we're just missing something.

Comment: Hmmm... Same in `nvi`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr;** `vim` is not `vi`.

In `vi`, you should use Control-T instead of Tab to indent a line.

If you find hard to retrain, you could add an input mode mapping from Tab to Control-T:

```
printf 'map! \x16\t \x14\n' >> ~/.nexrc
```

In the real `vi`, and in the `nvi` clone (used in FreeBSD), a control-D will erase *autoindent characters* up to the previous "shiftwidth" boundary. It will **not** erase the Tab or Space characters you entered by hand, either by pressing Control-I, Tab or Space.

Comment: It says in the manual that it should "Erase to the previous shiftwidth column boundary." (and that's all it says), but you are correct that it seems to only delete indentation that was inserted when a new line was opened in autoindent mode.

Comment: I see. So, it will ^T/^D indents and unindents in auto indent mode until you start typing something on the line, then ^T adds spaces to go to the next boundary, but ^D does nothing but insert ^D characters.

Answer (score 5):

This is part of that very bug-for-bug compatibility.

There is a lengthy discussion of it in commentary in the source, in `/usr/src/contrib/nvi/vi/v_txt.c`.  The input is treated as a literal `␄` character *unless* `ai` mode is on *and* the last character inserted was an autoindent character (either by <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or autoindent on a new line).

The commentary also notes that original `vi`'s <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> were even more restricted, only affecting the indent if they were the first thing typed in insert mode.

Comment: I hope you don't mind it, but the character you're using for `EOT`/`^D` (U+2404) is very hard to see with the default fonts -- it looks like some rendering artifact.